# Scikit Learn SVM - Input types

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Hy I am starting to learn Scikit learn, but I am not interested in this iris-date or orlando real estate price things that they use in all this tutorials. This does not make any sence for me. I want to use my own date, but I can not figure out what input format should be used.

This is how my Code looks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

x,y = [[1,2], [2,4]]

clf.fit(x,y)
```

I always geht the message:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [1, 2]

I tried many other formats like [[1],[1]] or 1,1.

So my simple questions, in witch formate do I have to write this 
"x,y = [[1,2], [2,4]]" for my data?

Also, how can I train a model to make a forecast, for example: I have 10 Sports Teams in one legue.

In my table I have:
Team 1 | Team 2 | Result | location

So I want to figure if 2 teams play against each other who will win, but the location of course can be a factor.

I want to predict if team A plays against B at home, who is more likly to win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to enter your data:**

The way you enter your data `x` contains just a single sample with 2 features, whereas `y` provides 2 labels.

Use this notation to get 2 samples with one feature each: `x,y = [[1],[4]],[2,4]`

Or, just to make it more obvious:

```
x = [[1],[4]]
y = [2,4]
```

Btw.: Given that you are new to Scikit learn, you should definitely try to do the same with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays.

**Make a classification:**

If you want to make a forecast about who wins, you need to follow a couple of steps:

  - Split you data, so that your features ("teamA", "teamB" and "location") are contained in you training data and the results represent the labels, e.g.:

```
x = [[teamA1,teamB1,Loc1],[teamA2,teamB2,Loc2],[teamA3,teamB3,Loc3],...]
y = [result1,result2,result3,...]
```

  - Fit your model as before

  - Make a prediction given your test data, e.g.:

```
x_test = [teamX,teamY,locX]  # data for which you want the forecast
clf.predict(x_test)          # this returns the estimated result
```

Comment: Ok, this works, thank you.
But is there a way to have a solution to ad 2 or more features?

Comment: What do you mean with solution? Do you want to make a prediction based on that data?
Btw: Please feel free to accepts my answer if it helped ;-)

Comment: For example: I have 10 Sports Teams in one legue. In my table I have:

1 Team | 2 Team | Result | location. So I want to figure if 2 teams play against each other who will win, but the location of course can be a factor.

Comment: Could you please edit your question accordingly, then I'll try to edit my answer

Comment: Thank you again.
This gives me: NameError: name 'teamA1' is not defined

Comment: Those names are just ment as variables. You will have to fill those lines with the respective values from your data. I am sure you will figure that out